# JS Functions to make an API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, request

I have the following code.

I'm trying to make an API call (retrieve) passing **since (obj.since)**, therefore, every time I make the call the API does not retrieve all data. However, so far, I haven't found the way to get since from the last record on my database.

```
var express = require("express");
var article = require("../models/article");
var request = require('request');


article.findOne({}, {since:1, _id:0}, { sort: { 'since' : -1 } }, function (err,obj) { 
         var **dataString** = `'{"consumer_key":"XXXXX", "access_token":"XXXXXXX", "since":"${obj.since}"}'`;

});

var options = {
    url: 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/v3/get',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: **dataString**     
    }


function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let package = JSON.parse(body);
        for(var attributename in package.list){
            var title = package.list[attributename]["given_title"] ;
            var url = package.list[attributename]["given_url"] ;
            var newArticle = {title: title, url: url, since: since}
            article.create(newArticle, function(error, newlyCreated){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(newlyCreated);
            }
        });
    }
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
};;

request(options,callback)
```

How can I make an API call getting the **obj.since** from the database (MongoDB) and pass it to an object (options)?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing async callback style operation in for loop which is causing this issue. I will change few things

- Change `findOne` to have `exec` at the end so it returns promise
- `article.create` already returns a promise if no callback specified.
- Convert request to a promise style.
- Use `for..of` loop to do async operation.

The code will look like this

```
var express = require("express");
var article = require("../models/article");
var request = require('request');

function hitApi(dataString) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/v3/get',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: dataString    
    }
    request(options, error, response, body => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}


async function perform() {
  const dataString = await article.findOne({}, {since:1, _id:0}, { sort: { 'since' : -1 } }).exec();
  const response = await hitApi(dataString);

  const package = JSON.parse(response.body);
  for (const attributename of package.list) {
      var title = package.list[attributename]["given_title"] ;
      var url = package.list[attributename]["given_url"] ;
      var newArticle = {title: title, url: url, since: since}
      const newlyCreated = await article.create(newArticle);
      console.log(newlyCreated);
  }
}
```

You can then call `perform` function. There might be few syntax error but you will get an idea.